# Are there any tricks for changing the height to width ratio of an image without making it look compressed?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

There are many times when I found the perfect picture for a slide show but after re-sizing it to the carousel desired height it is still too tall.

Besides cropping, are there any tricks to shave off height of a photo? I know it seems like a ridiculous answer, but maybe there are tools or methods out there for dealing with these problems I am not aware of.

Answer (score 3):

1. Crop it manually.
2. Add a plain background colour (or clone some of the existing background) to pad the image to obtain the correct ratio.
3. Use [Content-aware resizing](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/content-aware-scaling.html). This is a fairly new form of resizing which analyses the image, and tries to resize the image without losing perspective. This works great on landscapes, but not on faces. Try it, YMMV.

Comment: Depending on how much height or width you need to 'shave off', Content Aware Resize should do a good job. It's clever enough to recognise the areas of your image that contain the most detail (faces, for example) and avoid compressing them until it absolutely has to.

Comment: By the way @user3791372, you should delete points one and two from this answer and just include Content Aware – this is clearly the best solution for this question.

Comment: @Alex I'll leave them in because it's always good to be able to choose from a list of options and either try them out, or choose not to try them, rather than use just "the best" solution which can isolate you in a box over time.